# Java throwing out of memory exception before it's really out of memory?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, out-of-memory, large-data

I wish to make a large int array that very nearly fills all of the memory available to the JVM. Take this code, for instance:

```
    final int numBuffers = (int) ((runtime.freeMemory() - 200000L) / (BUFFER_SIZE));
    System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory());
    System.out.println(numBuffers*(BUFFER_SIZE/4)*4);
    buffers = new int[numBuffers*(BUFFER_SIZE / 4)];
```

When run with a heap size of 10M, this throws an OutOfMemoryException, despite the output from the printlns being:

```
9487176
9273344
```

I realise the array is going to have some overheads, but not 200k, surely? Why does java fail to allocate memory for something it claims to have enough space for? I have to set that constant that is subtracted to something around 4M before Java will run this (By which time the printlns are looking more like:
    9487176
    5472256
)

Even more bewilderingly, if I replace buffers with a 2D array:

```
buffers = new int[numBuffers][BUFFER_SIZE / 4];
```

Then it runs without complaint using the 200k subtraction shown above - even though the amount of integers being stored is the same in both arrays (And wouldn't the overheads on a 2D array be larger than that of a 1D array, since it's got all those references to other arrays to store).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is BUFFER_SIZE set to the size of the heap?

Comment: No, it is set to 16384 in this case.

Comment: So that is how much memory you want left to work with after filling the array?

Comment: Perhaps java fails to allocate a block of contiguous memory of the required size for the array, and so fails - but in the 2D array case it can put the smaller arrays into a number of different, smaller contiguous sections and is thus fine? I wasn't aware memory fragmentation was a thing in Java.

Comment: Ah, no, my explanation wasn't entirely clear - the numBuffers value divides the free memory up into segments of size BUFFER_SIZE for use in the 2D array scenario. I am not understanding why a 1D array of the same dimensions cannot be allocated instead.

Comment: The problem is that you can't get that much space ***as a single allocation***.  The heap is fragmented.

Comment: Unless this is an exercise, I would make the maximum heap 1 GB or more to start with.

Comment: Indeed this is an exercise -  normally someone would have to be quite mad to enforce a 10MB limit on the java heap (If you're that short on memory to start with you probably shouldn't be using Java, methinks).
But it's an interesting and annoying point that it doesn't seem possible to use all the memory you think you have in the way you might think you can...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VM will divide the heap memory into different areas (mainly for the garbage collector), so you will run out of memory when you attempt to allocate a single object of nearly the entire heap size.

Also, some memory will already have been used up by the JRE. 200k is *nothing* with todays memory sizes, and 10M heap is almost unrealistically small for most applications.

The actual overhead of an array is relatively small, on a 32bit VM its 12 bytes IIRC (plus what gets wasted if the size is less than the minimal granularity, which is AFAIK 8 bytes). So in the worst case you have something like 19 bytes overhead per array.

Note that Java has no 2D (multi-dimensional) arrays, it implements this internally as an array of arrays.

Comment: This makes some sense - is there any way to work around this (At least to some extent) to get me my giant array?

Comment: Larger heap obviously :) You can play with the garbage collectors settings on the command line. This allows some control over the size of the 'generations'. It can probably be tuned to allow allocations to very near the maximum heap size, but may impact performance of the GC.

Comment: Since my app is going to do virtually nothing except play with this one single array, GC performance isn't a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2D case, you are allocating more, smaller objects.  The memory manager is objecting to the single large object taking up most of the heap.  Why this is objectionable is a detail of the garbage collection scheme-- it's probably because something like it can move the smaller objects between generations and the heap won't accomodate moving the single large object around.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to memory fragmentation and the JVM's inability to allocate an array of that size given the current heap.

Imagine your heap is 10 `x` long:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Then, you allocate an object `0` somehere. This makes your heap look like:

```
xxxxxxx0xx
```

Now, you can no longer allocate those 10 `x` spaces. You can not even allocate 8 `x`s, despite the fact that available memory is 9 `x`s.

The fact is that an array of arrays does not suffer from the same problem because it's not contiguous.

**EDIT**: Please note that the above is a very simplistic view of the problem. When in need of space in the heap, Java's garbage collector will try to collect as much memory as it can and, if really, really necessary, try to compact the heap. However, some objects might not be movable or collectible, creating heap fragmentation and putting you in the above situation.

There are also many other factors that you have to consider, some of which include: memory leaks either in the VM (not very likely) or your application (also not likely for a simple scenario), unreliability of using `Runtime.freeMemory()` (the GC might run right after the call and the available free memory could change), implementation details of each particular JVM, etc.

The point is, as a rule of thumb, don't always expect to have the full amount of `Runtime.freeMemory()` available to your application.

Comment: Java *is* and *has been able* to relocate objects on the heap since at least Java5. Please don't spread FUD.

Comment: @Durandal -- Java can relocate *SOME* objects.  Large objects are a special case.

Comment: @Durandal - Along with heap compacting there's also object pinning, which prevents the GC from moving or collecting some objects freely. That leads to memory fragmentation. The answer very simplistic just to get the message across.

Comment: @Isoliviera: Admitted, there are scenarios where an object may not be moved. But your answer completely ignores that objects normally are movable by the GC and that in turn makes it look like objects are *never* movable.

Comment: @HotLicks: I can't find any source for 'large objects are never moved'. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Durandal -- First off, there is no single Java GC algorithm -- there are a half-dozen different schemes, depending on which JVM version you use and what the tuning parms are.  Next, it's very inefficient to move large objects, so all Java copying heap managers that I know of put large objects in a different pool/generation/whatever from ordinary small (under roughly 10K) objects.

Comment: @Durandal -- And even if the large object were placed in copied heap, one would need to never take more than half of available space, or else the next GC will choke, for lack of space into which to copy the object.

Comment: Thanks for the info - but my situation was happening right after the app had started - the heap hasn't had time to become fragmented yet.

Comment: @HotLicks At least the Oracle default client GC (no parameters given except -Xms130M/-Xmx130M) seems to be quite able to move byte[] of sizes in the MB range (tested with 1.7.0_4 and 1.6.0_32). Where did you get the notion of 'large objects are not moved' from? And did you confuse 'not moved' possibly with 'not moved unless unavoidable' (which I find more likely).